# Monterey, lock-screen & power

Tags: network, monterey, screen-lock

How can I stop monterey from powering off the screens on my m1 MacBook Air?

My problem is that I have a wired gigabit connection through an external monitor. When I lock the screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Splat</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>) it powers both screens off, and I lose network connectivity, which is nasty when I have a long-running task on a server ... yes, I do usually run those within a `screen` session, but I'd still prefer not falling off the network at all ... especially since it often takes up to 30 seconds after the power is back on for the network to spring back to life.

Comment: Did yip activate the checkbox for "Prevent your Mac from automatically sleeping when the display is off"? it's in ``Battery``->``Power Adapter``.

Comment: @MatthiasWinkelmann - I did/hab' ich. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the *solution* (workaround? kludge?) is **not** to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Splat</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>.

Instead I set the screensaver to require a password immediately, and make an automator quick action tied to a different keyboard combo that starts the screensaver.

Now I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Splat</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (note the **L** for **lock** ;)) and have the machine locked w/ the screens active and the network not dying on me.

Why the **lock** doesn't honour screensaver/energy settings is beyond me - what a stupid design decision.